# sorting based on specific order Sqlite

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table and need to it sort on two columns, first one is a varchar column and sencond is a date column...

problem is... for the first column I dont want sort based on alphabetic order

table stracture is

```
 id       name       status        date
 ---------------------------------------

 1        aaaa     completed      '2014-05-02'
 2        aaaa     Running        '2015-05-03'
 3        aaaa     new            '2015-05-03'
 4        aaaa     Pause          '2015-05-04'
 5        aaaa     completed      '2015-05-08'
```

I want status to be sorted like this

```
  id       name       status        date
 ---------------------------------------

  1       aaaa      Running      '2014-05-03'
  2       aaaa      Pause        '2014-05-04'
  3       aaaa      new          '2014-05-03'
  4       aaaa      completed    '2014-05-02'
  5       aaaa      completed    '2014-05-08'
```

but is sorting like this

I want status to be sorted like this

```
  id       name       status        date
 ---------------------------------------

  1       aaaa       Running      '2014-05-03'
  2       aaaa       Pause        '2014-05-04'
  3       aaaa       new          '2014-05-03'
  4       aaaa       completed    '2014-05-02'
  5       aaaa       completed    '2014-05-05'
```

any suggestion are appreciated...

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this....

```
SELECT  * FROM table 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN status = 'Running' THEN 1 
WHEN status = 'Pause' THEN 2
WHEN status = 'New' THEN 3 
WHEN status = 'Completed' THEN 4
WHEN status = 'Deleted' THEN 5 END), Date  ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

try this ..

**In Android**

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM "
                + TABLE_CONTACTS
                + " where isConvertToInvoice = 0 and loginUser_id ='"
                + logInID
                + "' ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = 'Running' THEN 1 WHEN status = 'Pause' THEN 2 WHEN status = 'new' THEN 3 WHEN status = 'Completed' THEN 4 END ";
```

**In ios**

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT  * FROM  TABLE_CONTACTS  where isConvertToInvoice = 0 and User_id ='%@'  ORDER BY CASE WHEN status = 'Running' THEN 1 WHEN status = 'Pause' THEN 2 WHEN status = 'new' THEN 3 WHEN status = 'Completed' THEN 4 END",logInID];
```